# Is it better to give an argument to `Array#flatten` when the max depth is known?

Tags: ruby, arrays

When you want to flatten an array all the way, where the maximum depth of the array is known, is it better in terms of performance to always pass that maximum depth as an argument to `Array#flatten`? For example, is it better to do the former than the latter in the following?

```
[[:foo], [:bar], [:baz], ...].flatten(1)

[[:foo], [:bar], [:baz], ...].flatten
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not on MRI, because the check whether an element is an array happens whether you set a level or not. It essentially does this (psuedo-Ruby, if you want the original C it starts [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L4148))

```
array.each do |value|
  if !value.is_array? || current_depth >= max_depth
    result << value
  else
    current_depth += 1
    recurse ...
  end
end
```

The actual implementation is not explicitly recursive and there's no `is_array?` method, but hey, you get the point.

The take-home message is that your use case will always hit the `!value.is_array?` condition, and will never use the argument you passed, so you don't gain anything by passing it.

Comment: even if the condition was swapped the performance gain would be negligible.